# Leaflet.Draw - Export file into modal attachment

Tags: javascript, leaflet, export, bootstrap-modal, attachment

So I have a tricky one here! I am battling to research this idea as I don't even know what to search for. Some quick background info: I have a Leaflet.Draw map that allows the user to download a drawn feature as a .kml file. When the submit button is clicked, the feature is exported and a contact form (as a modal) pops up which allows the user to provide some info and attach their exported feature (take a look at the screenshot).

[image: File exported and modal fired]

I thought it would be really cool if the exported feature was automatically uploaded to the form's attachment input. Is something like this possible?

Here is the export script:

```
    document.getElementById('export').onclick = function(e) {
        // Extract GeoJson from featureGroup
        var data = featureGroup.toGeoJSON();
        var kml = tokml(data);
        // Convert to dataURL format
        var convertedData = 'application/vnd.google-earth.kml+xml;charset=utf-8,' + encodeURIComponent(kml);

        // Create export
        document.getElementById('export').setAttribute('href', 'data:' + convertedData);
        document.getElementById('export').setAttribute('download','data.kml');
    }
```

And the attachment part of the form

```
<input type="file" name="file_attach[]" multiple data-required="true"/>
```

Thanks.

Comment: There is no screenshot in your post

Comment: Whoops, thanks for pointing that out. Screenshot has been added :)